# Return list of current Facebook user's friends PHP

Tags: php, image, facebook, vote

I am working on a Facebook app that will allows users to vote on their favorite pictures, based on their friend's profiles pictures. I know how to display the images, just not how to get the list of the current user's friend's IDs. My application is written in PHP. This is the last thing I need to complete the app. Any help would be great!

---

**This is my code:** (Just to display each user ID on the page)

```
<?php
include_once 'facebook.php';
$apikey = 'API KEY HERE';
$secretkey = 'SECRET KEY HERE';

$fbObj = new Facebook($apikey, $secretkey);

$myuid = $fbObj->require_login();

$friends = $fbObj->api('$myuid/friends');
echo $friends;
?>
```

That code raises the following PHP error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Facebook::api() in /home/zach/public_html/Majik/animated.php on line 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use Graph - then it is easy

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends
```

More details at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

After that you can iterate through the users list and use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/picture
```

to display user's picture.

Comment: I have tried that, but it want an authorization token. First I thought that was my API key, but it didn't work. And, using that link, how do I display the user id's on the page?

Comment: @Zachary Brown: well, you need to learn how to work with Graph then. You can start learning from http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

Comment: The authorization token is the one generated by OAuth, not API key or secret. For OAuth to generate the token, you need to login the user and do some server-dirty-talk :) @zerkms' tip to check the PHP lib is right on.

Comment: OK, I used a string of code that I found on line to attempt to get and print the token, but it either doesn't print the token, or the token is coming back empty. I appended it to my original post above.

Comment: @Zachary Brown: :-S have you looked at my link? PHP SDK library handles all tokens **automatically**!! You shouldn't even think about them - just use that SDK.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, I have. But, it still requires a token to make the call. I need to provide a token, in order to get the list.

Comment: My problem is, the token that Facebook is returning is not working when I make the call to get the friends list.

Comment: @Zachary Brown: again: if you're using PHP SDK that i gave - then you **should not take care** of any tokens. That library does everything automatically. Show us how you do perform the friends list request.

Comment: @zerkms, I added the call I use to get the friends list to the end of my original post above. Everything I can find on it requires an auth token to be added to the url.

Comment: @Zachary Brown: with what do you perform that query? Manually with curl/sockets? Or with official facebook PHP SDK? If you are not enough experienced to implement OAuth v2 protocol, why don't you take **ready-to-work** official library?

Comment: I'm still new to writing Facebook Apps, just figured someone here would be able to help. I'm very interested in **ready to work** anything, can you provide more details? I would rather learn from working code, then spend hours playing with broken code. :)

Comment: GOT IT! I figured out how to get the token, now I just need to know how to get the data from the friends URL, parse it and echo each user's ID. Ideas?

Comment: @Zachary Brown: I'm still insisting you on using official php sdk ;-) There is an example directory with sample script.

Comment: I am using the official PHP SDK from Facebook. I downloaded it from github.

Comment: @Zachary Brown: `$friends = $fb->api('me/friends');` - this is how you can retrieve current user's friends then.

Comment: I have tried it... and this is the PHP error in the server logs:   **PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function api() on a non-object in /home/zach/public_html/Majik/animated.php on line 11**

Comment: @Zachary Brown: well, have you created `$fb` object?

Comment: Yes, only I named it $fbobj:  **$fbobj = new Facebook($apikey, $secretkey);**

Comment: @Zachary Brown: update your question with actual php code you're working with now.

Comment: @Zachary Brown: 1. it is not possible that `$fbObj->require_login();` works fine and `$fbObj->api(...)` not. I don't believe. 2. use 'my/friends' instead. It always refers to current user's friends.

Comment: @Zachary Brown: btw, you can skype me (my name there is the same as nickname here) or email (it can be found in my CV). I have few spare time now to help.

Comment: @zerkms, it may not seem possible, but I think it might be obvious that it is. I tried replacing the user's ID with _my_, but that still did not correct the issue. I've also corrected a typo and posted the updated error message.

Comment: @Zachary Brown: "but that still did not correct the issue" --- sure, it will not. It is just more correct way to request the data you need in. Btw, what about `var_dump($fbObj);` right before require_login() and right after?

Answer (score 2):

copy the facebook api file into the same directory you are working from