# How do I get the total number of friends using the Facebook API and PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, api

How can I get the total number of friends using the Facebook PHP API?

This is my code so far:

```
<?php require_once 'facebook.php'; 
  $appapikey = 'x'; 
  $appsecret = 'x'; 
  $facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
  $user_id = $facebook->getuser(); $friends = ???;
```

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: <?php
 
require_once 'facebook.php';
 
$appapikey = 'x';
$appsecret = 'x';
 
$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
 
$user_id = $facebook->getuser();
 
$friends = ???;

Comment: accept as answer if it helps

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();  
$fbme= $facebook->api('/me');  
echo "Welcome ".$fbme['name'];  
$frnz= $facebook->api('/me/friends');  
echo "< br />Total Number of friends you have:".sizeof($frnz['data'])."< br/>";
```

Answer (score 3):

*Possible Duplicate: [Return List of Current Facebook Users Friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064974/return-list-of-current-facebook-users-friends-php)*

May want to check out the [Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user)

Comment: It's seems more like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527518/how-can-i-count-the-total-friends-of-a-facebook-user-by-uid

Comment: This is not an answer. And the OP does not ask for a list of friends, but simply the number of friends.

Answer (score 3):

Once you (or your user) has authorized your application, you can access a JSON array of users' friends by fetching `https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/friends`. The length of the array is the number of the user's friends.

Comment: Boy, that must be a long array for nutters who friend everything in sight.

Comment: by using this api user can only get a list of his own friends.

Answer (score 3):

This sizeof array thingy doesn't work, because facebook has a limited number of friends to show. instead, you should use the paging functionality of FB App response.
Also you can limit the number of friends you want to retrieve and place this kind of request in a loop:

```
$facebook->api('/me/friends?limit=$limit&offset=$offset');
```

you just need to place it in a while and go until no friends retrieved. in each loop, increase $offset. That should do.