# Count array items

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want to know how many friends a user has, to select a random friend.

I'm working with the Facebook API and I'm doing this call

```
$friendlist = $this->facebook->api('/me/friends');
```

Which returns the array $friendlist

```
Array (
    [data] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
              [name] => User Name
              [id] => XXXXXXXX
              )
        [1] => Array (
              [name] => User name
              [id] => XXXXXXXXXX
        )
        [2] => Array (
              [name] => User Name
              [id] => XXXXXXXX
        )
     )
   [paging] => Array (
       [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/1453123479/friendslimit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=1000059235606
      )
)
```

I'm trying this - as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379017/how-do-i-get-the-total-number-of-friends-using-the-facebook-api-and-php) - but it doesn't echo anything.

```
echo count($friendlist['data']);
```

Comment: How about `count($data['friendlist']['data'])` ?

Comment: `count($data['friendlist']['data'])` should give you the output `3`. Instead of just saying "it doesn't work", please explain what happens when you try it.

Comment: The array above is in $friendlist, sorry for the unclear explanation.

Comment: I'm working with CodeIgniter HMVC, thats why I'm using the $data['friendlist'] in my controller and use it as $friendlist in my view. :-)

Comment: can you post the whole code block, from array definition to the echo count()? is the array still available in the scope when you echo?

Comment: well, does this line really get executed, `echo count($friendlist['data']);` or the code exits before processing this line? Have you debugged this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

The number was added to the id - so I couldn't see it - as you can see here:

```
echo "my id is " . $user_id;

echo count($friendlist['data']);
```

I'm embarrassed, such a stupid mistake :(.

Thanks for the input tho!

Stijn

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to select a random friend, you can use the built in `PHP` function `rand()` to get a randomly selected index which you can use in your variable `$friendlist`.

```
function getRandomFriend() {
    $friendlist = $this->facebook->api( '/me/friends' );
    // Count the number of friends
    $numFriends = count( $friendlist[ "data" ] );
    // Random Number
    $randNum = rand( 0, $numFriends );
    return $friendlist[ "data" ][ $randNum ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting $data['friendlist'] to get that array so I'd expect to use the following:

```
echo count( $data['friendlist']['data'] );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but no. The data is in the array $friendlist, sorry for my unclear explanation.

Comment: I'm sorry my solution didn't work but something is unclear here. Count is  a basic function so providing you give it the correct array there isn't much room for error.